# I cant figure out how to use CloseShieldInputStream to wrap System.in for a scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So reading other posts i see that people are saying the the best way to fix the issue with closing a scanner, is to use CloseShieldInputStream to wrap system.in so that it doesnt close when you close the scanner.

this is one of the many variations ive tried but i cant figure out how to use it correctly

```
CloseShieldInputStream wrapped = new CloseShieldInputStream(System.in);
Scanner sIn1 = new Scanner(wrapped);
```

would anyone be able to advise me on how to use it correctly?

Comment: Why bother? Just don't close the `Scanner`.